# How to set the url_alias of a node using Drupal 8 Migrations

Tags: migration, drupal-8

I use the Migration facility included with Drupal 8 to create articles from a proprietary CMS. To decouple the legacy database from Drupal, I first export articles from my legacy CMS into a Yaml file. My articles have an URL like `http://example.com/article/123/some-slug.html`.

How do I set the url_alias of an article created through a migration to be `/article/123/some-slug.html`?

---

Some more context. My migration module `modules/custom/my_migration` looks like this:

### File `.../config/install/migrate.migration.my_article.yml`

```
id: my_article
label: Migrates my articles
migration_group: my_migration
source:
  plugin: my_article
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: article

  title: legacy_title

  # ... some more field mappings
```

### File `.../src/Plugin/migrate/source/Article.php`

```
<?php namespace Drupal\my_migration\Plugin\migrate\source;

use Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\source\SourcePluginBase;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

/**
 * Class Article
 *
 * @MigrateSource(
 *   id = "my_article"
 * )
 */
class Article extends SourcePluginBase {

  protected function initializeIterator() {
    $articles = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('migration-data/articles.yaml'));

    foreach ($articles as $article) {
      $article['id'] = 'article-' . $article['legacy_id']; 
    }
    return $articles;
  }

  public function fields() {
    return [
      'legacy_title' => $this->t('Article title'),
      'legacy_url' => $this->t('Article URL'),
    ];
  }
}
```

### File `migration-data/articles.yaml`

```
- legacy_id: 123
  legacy_title: 'Article #123'
  legacy_url: '/article/123/article-123.html'
- legacy_id: 456
  legacy_title: 'Article #456'
  legacy_url: '/article/456/article-456.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to set url alias

$system_path = '/node/'.$node->id();  //internal node path

$path_alias = '/article/'.$alias_slug;  // alias path

$langcode = 'en';

\Drupal::service('path.alias_storage')->save($system_path, $path_alias, $langcode);